# SSRS Group on multiple colums, total and expand

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

In ssrs, I have a dataset from a query(mssql db) that returns three columns:

dataset1

```
timestamp
customer
product
```

and I am trying to display a table that totals by timestamp(date only) and product, and the timestamp is collapsed on the date.  See example 1.

```
Date                   Customer      product    total
+ 07/12/2016           Max           Fork       5
+ 07/12/2016           Max           Spoon      4
+ 07/10/2016           Jim           Knife      11
+ 06/02/2016           Steve         Fork       6
```

Allowing the user to expand the Date to see rows for exact timestamp, like this...

```
Date                   Customer      product    total
- 07/12/2016           Max           Fork       5
 07/12/2016 16:25:12   Max           Fork       1
 07/12/2016 13:11:02   Max           Fork       1
 07/12/2016 12:45:45   Max           Fork       1
 07/12/2016 10:33:20   Max           Fork       1
 07/12/2016 08:25:55   Max           Fork       1
+ 07/12/2016           Max           Spoon      4
+ 07/10/2016           Jim           Knife      11
+ 06/02/2016           Steve         Fork       6
```

I get pieces working here and there, but not all together. Any help would be appreciated. I'm rather new to creating tables from scratch and with complexity. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm starting with this sample dataset

```
Date    Customer    Product
2016-07-15 02:14:15.777 Max Fork
2016-07-15 03:14:15.777 Max Fork
2016-07-15 04:14:15.777 Max Fork
2016-07-15 05:14:15.777 Max Fork
2016-07-15 06:14:15.777 Max Fork
2016-07-15 03:14:15.777 Max Spoon
2016-07-15 04:14:15.777 Max Spoon
2016-07-15 05:14:15.777 Max Spoon
2016-07-15 06:14:15.777 Max Spoon
```

Here's how I would go about it

Start with a blank table on your report, set its dataset (mine is just DataSet1).

Now put in the details row first.  You didn't indicate you're returning metrics from the db so I assume each record is a 1 (?).  I set the table up this way:

[image]

Which renders like this

[image]

Next, we want to create a parent group.  With the table selected, right-click the "Details" Row Group and select **Add Group > Parent Group...**

In the Group By box, put =1.  We will change this later.  Check Add Group Header.  Click OK.

[image]

This will have added a new column on the left which we don't want so you can delete that column (but just the column, not the group!).

It should end up like this:

[image]

Back down in the Row Groups area, double click the new Group to open the Group Properties.  In the Group On section, change the expression from the "=1" we put in earlier to this

```
=FORMAT(Fields!Date.Value, "MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Next, add Customer And Product as additional grouping columns then click OK.

[image]

Now back in the table, set the group's Date column cell value to the same expression used to group it:

```
=FORMAT(Fields!Date.Value, "MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Customer and Product are the same, but in the Total column, set the expression to

```
=COUNT(1)
```

[image]

Here's the preview so far

[image]

All that is left to do is to collapse the groups and make them so they can be toggled.

Click the textbox you want to be the Toggle and take note of the text box's name.  For me it is Textbox68.

Double-click the details row group again to open the properties.  Go to the visibility section.  Set it to "Hide", and check the "Display can be toggled by this report item:".  Select the appropriate textbox (in my case it was Textbox68)

Here is the preview

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed.